# I have file which is pipe delimited. I have 28 fields. I have to remove the last 2 fields and print only 26 fields

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have file which is pipe delimited. I have 28 fields. I have to remove the last 2 fields and print only 26 fields.

These are the last 3(26,27,28) fields `DC||0|`

My desired output is `|DC|`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106951/discussion-on-question-by-nikhil-i-have-file-which-is-pipe-delimited-i-have-28).

Comment: Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any POSIX-compliant sed:

```
sed 's/\([^|]*|\)\{2\}$//'
```

e.g.:

```
$ echo 'foo|DC||0|' | sed 's/\([^|]*|\)\{2\}$//'
foo|DC|
```

Comment: This is assuming that fields end with a `|` (which is the opposite of what awk does).

Comment: No, in awk terms you could think of it as assuming that records end with `|\n` and are separated into fields at each `|` within those records. Doesn't matter how we think of it though - per the question the OP has input where the last 3 fields **to them** are `DC||0|` and removing their last 2 fields will output `|DC|` and that's what this does.

Comment: If, and that is usually a big if, the OP is actually understanding correctly what a field is.  The last four fields could be: `DC|a|0|b` and he is misunderstanding the empty last field. Which I believe he is.

Comment: Sure, anything's possible, but we DO see questions at times about, for example, input lines that start and end with `|`s like `|a|b|c|d|` which **to the person posting the text** would represent 4 fields with the values a, b, c, and d so so far I don't see any reason to think the OP is wrong about what the data they posted means to them.

Comment: Sure, Ed, that could be, and has been (sometimes) a valid description of field delimiters. However, all I meant to say is that awk divides fields on the delimiter, so, for awk, a `|a|b|c|d|` (with  FS="|") means 6 fields : empty, a, b, c, d, e, empty.  That is the usual interpretation. Any other interpretation is inusual.

Comment: Yes, that is the usual interpretation, it's just my personal opinion that that's not what the OP has based on the text and example in their question but I could be wrong and it's definitely is a possibility that that the OP has misunderstood their data, mis-stated their requirements and provided a bad example of their real data such that some of the solutions posted will fail with different samples of their data.

Answer (score 2):

With **GNU** awk:

```
awk '{NF=NF-3; NF++}1' FS='|' OFS='|' file
```

This removes last three columns and adds one empty.

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NF>2{NF-=2;$1=$1;print}'
```

With some (but not all!) awk variants you can omit the `$1=$1`.

In the case where there are less than 3 fields on the line, this will not print the line at all; it's the only way to ensure that a difference is made between a line with an empty starting field, and one with less than 3 fields.

When the field-separator (`FS`) is not a single space, each match of it will delimit fields, and empty leading and trailing fields are NOT trimmed.

In a line like `DC||0|`, there are 4 fields (`DC`, `<empty>`, `0`, `<empty>`), not 3. Removing the last 2 will result in `DC`, `<empty>` => `DC|` when joined with `|`.

Similarly, in a line like `|DC|`, there are 3 fields (`<empty>`, `DC`, `<empty>`), not 1, and removing the last 2 will result in `<empty>`, ie an empty line without any `|`.

Comment: In a line like `DC||0|` there are 3 fields if the OP tells us there are 3 fields, which in this case they did. Just because the OPs fields are separated with `|`s there's no reason to think the OPs lines aren't terminated with `|\n` exactly like the OP showed in their example: "These are the last **3**(26,27,28) fields `DC||0|`" (highlight mine).

Comment: To match OP's desired output (trailing field separator), it should be `print $0,""`

Comment: @Fiximan with your edit, it would've printed `...|DC||` instead of `...|DC|`. Have you tested it?

Comment: I start by `echo "DC||0|"`. A pure `print` will result in `DC|` only because of the empty field between `DC` and `0`. It might be possible, to have data like `DC|1|0|` and this would then result in `DC|1`. How fields should be counted is explained in this very answer itself. OP seems not to be fully aware of how to count fields or is a bit unspecific in this respect and what "remove last 2 fields" means to him. Assuming is means that lines have a trainling `|` and the last field after that is not counted in OP's logic, the proper code should be `{NF-=3;$1=$1;print $0,""}`. OP must specify.

Answer (score 0):

I used `cut -d "|" -f 1-26 <filename>` and it worked.